# Can I say that Integration can be equal to the formula of finding the area of a right triangle?

Tags: integration, triangles, area

Let us have a certain function like $f(x)=x$

In the world of integration, can I say that $\int_{0}^bxdx=\frac{1}{2}(b)(f(b))$?
Because if you look at graph of function x, it would look like something 45° right triangle (though we can probably change its angle using the trig func $\tan$ and multiplying it by x like this $f(x)=x\tan(s°)$ or in integration $\int_{0}^bx\tan(s°)dx=\frac{1}{2}(b)(b\tan(s°))$ or making it more complicated $\int_{a}^bx\tan(s°)dx=(\frac{1}{2}(b)(b\tan(s°)))-\frac{1}{2}(a)(f(a))$ where s° is your/the preferred angle.

Note: we're using degrees in tan not radian.

Comment: Yes, but this will only work if you’re integrating lines through the origin, of course.

Comment: Further to @symplectomorphic's comment, an integral under a line, neither end on the $y$-axis, is a trapezium. This is the basis of the trapezium rule.

Comment: Any definite integral of function $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is the area under the curve of the function. So in your case, $a=0,b=b$ and the shaded area is a triangle, hence the area is $1/2*$base$*$height

Comment: Your "$\int x dx= \frac{1}{2}bf(b)$ doesn't even make sense because there is no "f" on the left side!  Yes, in the special case f(x)= x that is true because $\int x dx= \frac{1}{2}x^2+ C$ (you really shouoldn't ignore the "+ C".) But if, for example $f(x)= x^3$, $\int x^3= \frac{1}{3}x^4+ C$, not anything like what you have.  The fact that, for y= f(x)= x, the graph is a straight line through the origin, the "area under the graph" is a right triangle is trivial.  But that is a very limited example.

Comment: "because there is no "f" on the left side!" I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Isn't the answer would be equal? It's a definite integral so I didn't try to add "C" BTW.